# Is there a DAX function that can run multiple IF statements over a group of ID's?

Tags: sql, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, dax

As you can see I have a list of Id's and the time they were processed and whether it was successful.

What I need is to identify all SapBpId's where the 2ndLatest Date succeeded and the Latest Date failed.

Something Like:
Is2ndLatestDate = "2nd Latest" && IsSuccess = true
IsMaxDate = "Latest" && IsSuccess = false
return SapBpId

Even if the ID has 700 entries I only care about the last 2 date entries and only if it succedded first and then failed on the latest try.

BONUS Points for anyone who can write it in a SQL query that can be run on a Cosmosdb (that's where this data is coming from).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Column to you table:

```
Problem = 
var SapId = SAP[SapBpld]
return
COUNTROWS(FILTER(SAP;SAP[SapBpld] = SapId && ((SAP[lsMaxDate] = "Latest" && not SAP[IsSuccess]) || SAP[is2ndLatestDate] = "2nd Latest" && SAP[IsSuccess]))) =2
```

The Column Problem is added and it will set a true on all id's which comply to your needs above

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Exactly what I needed.  Didn't think about using 'return'.  Thank you!